# How to transform many numbers into one? Algorithmic issue

Tags: algorithm, encoding, graph, bit-manipulation, transformation

I want to have function that transform input (n-size vector) into one int.

Formally:

F: (x1,x2,...,xn) -> y

This could be something like:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering
but should be:
-unambiguous
-big size of input cant produce huge output number.

My case is to encode graph neighbours. I just want to keep information about edges for specific vertex.

First idea was that assume some vertex has assigned value 41. In binary representation it is 101001. That means this vertex is connected with vertices numer: 1, 4 and 6. Then getting info about neighbors was simply tab[i] & (1 << j), where tab is 1-d array of vertices and for vertex i it stores for example 41. j is a number of checking vertex. But with this solution is on problem: I can only encode information about 32 neighbours (max size of int - 2^32) or am I wrong?

So I want to have simply representation of graph neighbours as a number with fast method of obtaining info about neighborhood of two vertices. Is such a solution exist, or maybe some of u have an idea how to deal with it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your limit in the scheme you describe is not 32 *neighbors*, but 32 vertices total.  is there some reason you don't want to use an adjacency matrix, where adj[i][j] = 1 iff vertex i is a neighbor of vertex j?

Comment: Yes, it is. My purpose is to write efficient algorithm of graph computing on GPU, where input problem could be huge sized. Hence, matrix n x n could be not fitted into limited GPU memory.

And yes, I know my scheme limited me to only 32 vertices :) 
That's why I'm here with my problem :)

Comment: Suppose we have `k` bits available for storing information about neighbours of vertex. Then of course you can store at most `2^k` combinations of sets of neighbours.  You can store then in array or any other associative container. But I dont see why you can't use ajacency list or ajacency matrix?

Comment: Minimal size of memory used, and minimal time cost of computation -  things I want to achieve. 

GPU makes the second, but first is still an open issue.

Comment: I'm curious what graph algorithm do you want to make parallel on gpu. They are hard to make parallel in general.

Comment: You can pass adjacency lists to GPU in this way: offsets[], lists[]. Where offsets[] is an array of pairs of indicies pointing to lists. offsets[v] defines continuous interval in lists which corressponds to adjacency list of vertex v

Comment: For arbitrary input graphs, adjacency matrices and your adjacency bitmaps both have O(v^2) space performance. Adjacency lists have O(nv) performance, where n is the upper bound on the degree of each vertex. So if n < v you might be able to do better.  But you haven't told us anything about what kind of graphs you intend to work with.

Comment: @Jim adjacency lists have O(n + m) performance.

Comment: Input: graph G=(V,E) and integer k
Output: is chromatic number <= k 

so as you see - graph coloring. 

Simple things are fulfilling the internet, so why not to try do something harder? I know I can, but still searching better option. As I said, performance first of all. And I dont know if GPU can store (for example) 10000x10000 byte matrix. And consider cost of thread communication.

Comment: @piotrekg2 Actually I have implemented exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @JimLewis Any kind of graph (full, rare,...) but with huge amount of data. Purpose: make the most efficient algorithm on GPU as I can.

Comment: Of course I dont want you to help me with an algorithm itself - I want to do it myself. Just asking you if u have any idea of unconventional graph encoding. But maybe such thing doesnt exist... yet ;)

Comment: @user2248836 but the problem is that you don't want to optimize for memory size only but you probably want memory layout to be "thread friendly" also

Comment: Yes, I do. Something I propose on the post (32 vertices limit) is memory efficient and "thread friendly" (simply operations). So it would be perfect, unless this limit...

Comment: @user2248836 just a silly suggestion but the adjacency matrix is just a 2D 1-bit texture or not ? so I do not see any problems with passing it to GPU. the same goes for your bitmask you can use any bit-count you need ... until you hit the max texture resolution barrier of coarse ...

Comment: The best you can probably do is make use of bitset. In c++: [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible.

If you have k potential neighbors,then your representation needs to `2^k` possible values so as to map a value to a certain combination of neighbors. So you do need at least `k` bits to represent `k` neighbors.

Also, your proposed solution of using a 32 bit int to represent neighbors is not much different from an adjacency matrix. In fact its exactly the same thing, except you are using bits instead of maybe using booleans. You could use an array of bit vectors instead of of using 2-D array of booleans.

Comment: I dont agree with you. Cause I think it's not impossible, it's not invented yet :) 

My solution in fact isn't much different, but bit operations are faster than any other.

Anyway, thanks u all for answers. If u ever invent such thing as 'graph encoding' (like Godel numbering) - let me know :)